# Boost Graph bellman_ford_shortest_paths with labeled_graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm trying to run the Bellman-Ford algorithm using the Boost Library. I have a labeled graph, but I'm getting an exception `invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int`. Any help would only be appreciated. Here is my code:

```c++
// g++ -std=c++17 -Wall test.c++ -l boost_system && ./a.out 

#include <iostream>                  // for cout
#include <utility>                   // for pair
#include <algorithm>                 // for for_each
#include <vector>                    // For dist[] and pred[]
#include <limits>                    // To reliably indicate infinity
#include <map>
#include <list>

#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/directed_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/labeled_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

class Node
{
  public:
    int id;
    int group;
};

struct EdgeProperties {
  double weight;

  EdgeProperties(){}
  EdgeProperties(double w){ weight = w; }
};

typedef labeled_graph<adjacency_list<hash_setS, hash_setS, directedS, Node, EdgeProperties>, int> Graph;

int main(){

    cout << "Calling main()" << endl;

    Graph g;

    // populate the graph
    {
        add_vertex( 0, g );
        g[0].id  = 0;
        g[0].group = 10;
        add_vertex( 1, g );
        g[1].id  = 1;
        g[1].group = 20;
        add_edge_by_label( 0, 1, EdgeProperties(110), g);
        add_edge_by_label( 1, 0, EdgeProperties(222), g);
        print_graph(g, get(&Node::id, g));
        cout << "There are " << num_vertices(g) << " nodes and " << num_edges(g) << " edges in the graph" << endl;
    }

    // number of verticies in the graph
    auto n = num_vertices(g);

    // weight map
    auto ewp = weight_map(get(&EdgeProperties::weight, g.graph()));

    const int source = 0;
    const int target = 1;

    // Distance Map (with n elements of value infinity; source's value is 0)
    auto inf = numeric_limits<double>::max();
    vector<double> dist(n, inf);
    dist[source] = 0.0;

    // Predecessor Map (with n elements)
    vector<int> pred(n);

    bellman_ford_shortest_paths(
        g.graph(), 
        n, 
        ewp
            .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(dist.begin(), get(&Node::id, g)))
            .predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(pred.begin(), get(&Node::id, g)))
    );

    return 0;
}
```

I saw the example on https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/example/bellman-example.cpp but the example uses not a labeled graph.

Here is a live preview of my code:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/WsQA8A0IyRvGWTIj

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem *has* been touched upon in the existing answer you accepted.

However, there's more to this.

Firstly, you're pretty much "within your right" to want use `Node::id` as the vertex index, and there could be many good reasons to use something else than `vector` as the *vertex container selector*¹.

Secondly, that stuff should... probably have worked. [`bellman_ford` documents](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/graph/doc/bellman_ford_shortest.html):

> The PredecessorMap type must be a Read/Write Property Map which key and vertex types the same as the vertex descriptor type of the graph.

And [`iterator_property_map` documents](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/property_map/doc/iterator_property_map.html):

> This property map is an adaptor that converts any random access iterator into a Lvalue Property Map. The OffsetMap type is responsible for converting key objects to integers that can be used as offsets with the random access iterator.

Now [LValuePropertyMap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/property_map/doc/LvaluePropertyMap.html) *might* in fact be readonly, but in this case it clearly shouldn't be.

When using `make_iterator_property_map` with the additional id-map parameter, it should in fact be behaving like any associative property map both the key and value types `vertex_descriptor` as required by the algorithm.

> **UPDATE** See "BONUS" below

I might dive in a little more detail later to see why that didn't work, but for now let's just work around the issue without modifying the graph model:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84831f4b29cd1309)</kbd>**

```
auto gg = g.graph();
auto id = get(&Node::id, gg);
std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, Graph::vertex_descriptor> assoc_pred;

bellman_ford_shortest_paths(gg, n,
    weight_map(get(&EdgeProperties::weight, gg))
    .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(dist.begin(), id))
    .predecessor_map(make_assoc_property_map(assoc_pred))
    );
```

That works as it should and as expected:

```
Calling main()
1 --> 0 
0 --> 1 
There are 2 nodes and 2 edges in the graph
```

## BONUS

I found the missing link: the predecessor map was defined with the wrong value-type:

```
vector<Graph::vertex_descriptor> pred(n);
```

Will obviously work: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f1f05a9626422f6)</kbd>**

---

¹ that's subtly different from the vertex descriptor, but related in the sense that the choice of vertex container will usually predict the actual type of vertex descriptor

Comment: Will look a bit more at the reason why the other approach failed to compile.

Comment: Yup. It was simple after all. Easy to overlook, so no worries :)